# SharePoint Rest API URL to filter records from list

Tags: rest, filter

I have list called Users.

[image]

In users list, column called **Age** of type Number.

Using Rest API I'm trying to get users whose age is between 50 to 100.

I need only the URL to filter these records.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something along the lines of this:

`/_api/Web/Lists/getbytitle('Users')/items?$filter=Age ge 50 and Age le 100`

Answer (score 3):

The appropriate url will be

```
{site url}/_api/Web/Lists/getbytitle('Users')/items?$filter=Age ge 50 and Age le 100
```

But if you only want specific columns from it, go for

```
{site url}/_api/Web/Lists/getbytitle('Users')/items?$select=Name,Age,Sex&$filter=Age ge 50 and Age le 100
```